# PGFPlot with data that is way too small

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the Wien and Rayleigh-Jeans laws in a graph of `$I \times \nu$`.

```
Wien Law:
\[ I=\frac{2h\nu^3}{c^2}e^{-\textstyle\frac{h\nu}{kT}}\]

Rayleigh-Jeans Law:
\[I=\frac{2k\nu^2T}{c^2}\]
```

But PGFPlot always crashes because the constants (in SI units) are way too small!
Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Edit: My actual code with just Wien's Law is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\nu$,
    ylabel = {$I(\nu,T)$ em $T=8.10^{-3}K$},
]

\addplot [
domain=0:10, 
samples=100, 
color=red,
]
{(1.48*10^(-50))*(x^3)*exp((-6*10^(-9))x)};
\addlegendentry{Lei de Wien}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I don't know what the best domain is.

Comment: Could you show us the code that crashes as well?

Comment: edited with my code

Answer (score 1):

Using a scratch plot and adding some of the commands from the O.P. code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
  grid=both,
  axis lines=middle,
  width=6cm,
  height=8cm,
  scale only axis,
}






\begin{document}

\def\planck{6.6e-34}
\def\light{3e8}
\def\temperature{5800}
\def\kB{1.38e-23}
\def\pivalue{3.14159}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\nu$,
    ylabel = {$I(\nu,T)$ em $T=8.10^{-3}K$},
]
\addplot[samples=200,red, line width = 1pt,domain=0:4e14]{ 2*\planck*x^3 / (\light^2)*exp(-(\planck *x) / (\kB* \temperature)};
\addlegendentry{Lei de Wien};
\addplot[samples=200,blue, line width = 1pt,domain=0:4e14]{ 2* \kB * x^2 * \temperature/\light^2};
\addlegendentry{Lei de Rayleigh};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

%\addplot[samples=200,black, line width = 1pt,domain=0:4e14]{ (8.0 * \pivalue * \planck / \light^3) * x^3 * 1.0/(exp((\planck *x) / (\kB* \temperature) -1))};
```

[image]

Comment: Works nicely until I change the temperature to 8e-3. Why does it crash then?

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro: The units -- I'll try to improve

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works fine here, you just forgot a multiplication sign (`*`) before the last `x`, and there's an extra `)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
  grid=both,
  axis lines=middle,
  width=6cm,
  height=8cm,
  scale only axis,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $\nu$,
    ylabel = {$I(\nu,T)$ em $T=8.10^{-3}K$},
    ylabel style={left}
]

\addplot [
domain=0:10, 
samples=100, 
color=red,
]
{(1.48*10^(-50))*(x^3)*exp((-6*10^(-9))*x};
\addlegendentry{Lei de Wien}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds fair. It crashed mostly because of the temperature I think.
(I need T=8e-3)